# function trouble about find largest in array

Tags: c, arrays, function

write a program that enter a series of integer(stores in array),then sorts the integer by calling the function  selection_sort. When given an array with n elements, selection_sort must do the following:
1.search the array to find the largest,then move it to the last position.
2.call itself recursively to sort the first n-1 elements of the array.

following is my code i think the code is errors everywhere i hope some master can help me

```
#include <stdio.h>

int selection_sort(int a[])//this function have error that "i"and"count"is undeclared
{
   int max = 0;
   for (i = 1; i <= count; i++)// continuous compare to final
   {
      if (a[i] > max)
      {
         max=a[i];
      }
   }
   a[count] = a[i]; //put the max to last position 
   count--;
}

int main(void)
{
   int a[100] = { 0 },i=0,count=0;
   while (1)
   {
      scanf("%d",&a[i]);
      if (a[i] = '\n') { break; }//this line have error because '\n' not "int" so when i "enter" it would not break 

      i++;   
      count++;   //counting how many integer i scanf
   }

   selection_sort();//call this function (i don't know well about function so i don't known where to put is correct )

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code has syntax errors. How does `selection_sort` see `count`?  Also, your logic `a[i] == '\n' )` is flawed. `a[i]` is never going to be `'\n'`. Also, you are accessing the array with starting index `1` in `selection_sort`. That needs to be `0`.

Comment: codeSmellHomework++;    // grin

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare. BUt you are assigned..

change this `if (a[i] = '\n') { break; }` to `if (a[i] == '\n') { break; }`.

You should change follows in your code.

1) change your function call..
2) declare `count` and `i` in function..
3) for taking values in to array,follow other method..

Try yourself...

Comment: int main(void)
{
 int a[100] = { 0 },i=0,count=0;

 while (1)
 {
  scanf("%d",&a[i]);
  if (a[i] == '\n') { break; }

  i++;   
  count++;   
 }

 
 printf("%d", a[2]);
         return 0;
}

Comment: i use this to debug but it doesn't break

Comment: OK. i have class latter ,i will try when i come back

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code.Basically there are many syntax and logical error in your code. Consider this as refer and compare with your original source.

```
 int selection_sort(int a[], int count){ 
    int max = 0, i =0;

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
        if (a[i] > max)
        {
            max=a[i];
        }
    }

    a[count] = max; 
    count--;

    return 0;
}

int main(void) { 

    int a[100] = { 0 },i=0,count=0;;
    printf ("Enter the total num\n");

    scanf("%d",&count);

    if ( ( count  ) >= (sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])) )
    return -1;

    while (i < count){
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
        i++;   
    }

    selection_sort(a, count);

    printf ("\nmax:%d\n", a [count]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help,i will compare with mine latter ,i should go to calss.

Comment: if i also have problem,i still need your help . thanks